# How to automatically select check box based on the data in Angular

Tags: angular

[image: view this]

I want to automatically selected check box using this list.

html

```html
  <div>
      <form [formGroup]="myForm">
          <ul class="chat-user-list">
              <li *ngFor="let empl of emp">
                  <a>
                      <div class="media">
                          <span class="avatar"><img alt="" src="assets/img/profiles/avatar-09.jpg"></span>
                          <div class="media-body align-self-center text-nowrap">

                              <div class="user-name">{{empl.employeeName}}</div>

                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                              <input type="checkbox"  
                                  (change)="addEmployee(empl.employeeGuid, $event.target.checked)"
                                  (change)="viewAddedEmployees(empl.employeeName, $event.target.checked)">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </a>

              </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" (click)="submitSelectedEmployee()" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <!-- <pre>Form values: {{myForm.value | json}}</pre> -->
  </div>
```

ts

```js
     this.assignedEmpList = this.indivijualTask.taskAssignedEmployeeList;
```

this `variable(assignedEmpList)` stores the checked data and the console result is shown above

Comment: You can use the `assignedEmpList` to bind to the `[checked]` property of your input element. Something like this: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xpjszq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: not working this

Comment: Add the TS file